# Django rest framework error : File field is required when using FileForm even though the file is recieved from request

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I am trying to upload file on django backend . The is being received and i am to access it from request.FILES["file"] but the file form keeps giving me error about that the file field is required even though i am passing the file.

This is view for uploading the file

```
class FileViews(APIView):
    
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def post(self,request):
        try:
            file = request.FILES.get("file")
            user_id = request.POST["user_id"]
            
            if not file or not user_id:
                return Response({"message": "Both 'file' and 'user_id' are required."}, status=rest_framework.status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            file_form = FilesForm( data = { "file_store" : file,"file_size":file.size,"user_id":user_id})
            if file_form.is_valid():
                file_form.save()
                print(file_form.cleaned_data)
                response = {"message" : "File is uploaded"}
                return Response(response , status = rest_framework.status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
            else:
                response = {"message" : file_form.errors}
                return Response(response , status=rest_framework.status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            response = {"message" : str(e)}
            return Response(response , status = rest_framework.status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

File form

```
class FilesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Files
        fields = '__all__'
```

and the file model

```
class Files(models.Model):
   
    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True) 
   
    file_size = models.PositiveIntegerField("file size(in Bytes)",default=0)
    
    file_store = models.FileField(upload_to=f"../uploads/{datetime.datetime.now()}")
    
    file_compressed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt include parser class for uploading file
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )
This seems to have fixed my issue.
Thanks.